# Liberty migration

Tags: migration, libraries, websphere-liberty

I had trying to migrate my project from WebSphere 8.0.0.12 to Liberty server. I tried to achieve this migration by resolving issues which mentioned in the analysis report generated by IBM migration Tool. One of these issues is Third-party APIs are unavailable on Liberty. My question is that these libraries are already existed into lib folder of my project, so how to add those jar files to be available in liberty. It should be added in server.xml or in applicationconfig.xml. I'm really confused.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to add a library element to your server.xml as mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html)

> Liberty libraries have three elements; folder, file, and fileset. For example:

```
<library>
   <folder dir="..." />
   <file name="..." />
   <fileset dir="..." includes="*.jar" scanInterval="5s" />
</library>
```

> A specified file must be a container for the resource (for example a JAR file) rather than the resource itself.
>
> If an element in the list is a file, the contents of that JAR or compressed .zip file are searched. If a folder is specified then resources are loaded from that directory.

As an example, you could add Derby using the following:

```
<library id="DerbyLibrary">
   <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib" includes="derby.jar"/>
</library>
```